# Cleansing $_GET Data -- PHP

Tags: php

I'm expecting to get and use an integer between 0 and 10 for a `$_GET` variable.  Like this: `http://example.com?id=5`

For cleansing `$_GET['id']` is it sufficient to just do this...

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id_test = (int)$_GET['id']; //Use the integer version of the input.

    if($id_test > 0 && $id_test <= 10) { //Make sure the integer version of the incoming $_GET['id'] is in the acceptable range.
        $id = $id_test;
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid entry';
        exit;
    }

    //Now use $id to update MySQL database, etc.
}
```

Shouldn't doing `$id_test = (int)$_GET['id'];` render any malicious user-submitted code (like dropping a table) useless?  Is this open to other attacks that I'm not thinking of?

Thanks.

Comment: Should do the trick. But if you use something like PDO to connect to your database, and use it properly, the submitted content should be escaped and cleaned anyway.

Comment: @Gladen haha i was about to say the same. Here is a easy tutorial for pdo. Check the prepared statements http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html

Comment: This may not be wise, but I'm hoping to avoid having to deal with PDO, etc. by cleansing the data this way.  Is this open to some kind of attack or is it bad practice for some reason?

Comment: That **IS** enough.  Even null is converted to integer 0. Anyting is converted to integer.  There is no way that someting after casting to integer has other than an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting to int should be enough in this case, but keep in mind this does not mean you should not use a prepared statement - cast the variable to int **AND** use prepared statements (if applicable).

Comment: Not questioning your knowledge, but merely asking... why are the prepared statements necessary if I've eliminated the threat of stuff like a user submitting code to "DROP_TABLE" or something like that?

Comment: in this specific case, its only from a performance standpoint, if you're going to call it several times, a prepared statement would be faster. but if you're going to call it only 1 time, i'm betting a simple query would be faster.

Comment: I am not familiar with that specific case, but I doubt the author needs every last drop of performance squeezed from the code. I am advertising prepared statements as a good practice - it is good thing to make it a habit to always use prepared statements. Aside from that @hanshenrik is right - a single query will be faster. But a prepared statement is more maintainable - someone might remove the (int) cast by accident which cannot happen to a whole statement, also if the query ever needs to be extended (additional where clauses), having a prepared statement already in place is a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

the solution here: filter_var with FILTER_VALIDATE_INT ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php )

```
if(!array_key_exists('id',$_GET) || false===filter_var($_GET['id'],FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,array('options'=>array('min_range'=>0,'max_range'=>10))))
{echo "invalid entry.";exit;}
```

your suggestion of just casting it to int, would give the result for 0  when $_GET['id']="puppy" , or similar. note also that filter_var may sometimes return  int 0 here, and when it returns 0, it will be "kindof like false" with type juggling, so use ===  , not == here.

Comment: I'm ok with `$_GET['id']="puppy"` being 0 because I'm expecting an integer of 1-10 to be submitted.  If someone's trying to submit "puppy", they should get an error.

Comment: Yeah, when people submit "puppy", they should get an error. when people submit 0 , should they also get an error? your cast-to-int solution will treat "puppy" and 0 alike.

Comment: Yes.  Thus the `$id_test > 0` in the "if statement".